# How to let users register for API access on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, authentication, registration

I have an API I want to demo online, but I want to restrict access to it (limited # of requests per minute).

Ideally I'd like users to be able register for access using an email, and then give them a API key.

Is there some prepackaged solution for doing this which would work on AWS?